# Linux: can't get out of Ctrl-Alt-F7 with no X server running

Tags: linux, tty

I'm currently logged in (locally) to a machine and was running in a TTY session without having started an X server. I accidentally hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F7</kbd> bringing me to where the graphical shell *would* be if it was running. The trouble is, I can't get back. I assume going to another TTY is forbidden using the standard <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> to protect students who have logged in to KDE or whatever, locked the screen, but don't realize that anyone could come along and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> into their TTY session. The trouble is that there is no X server running, and so I can't exit from it, and am stuck in the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F7</kbd> TTY which just has a cursor blinking at the top left of the screen.

Is there another way to switch currently-viewed TTY? How can I get out of this?

***Things that do not work:***

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Backspace</kbd>
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Sysrq</kbd>-<kbd>REISUB</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

If the machine is remotely accessible (via `ssh` or otherwise), run `chvt 1` as root.

Still, you can't switch to a VT that hasn't been allocated, so perhaps X was running and got wedged?  It might not be possible to escape from that.

Comment: X was not running, the VT I'm trying to switch to has indeed been allocated. I should add that I do not have root. This is a lab machine at my university

Comment: @Mala: Then *something* (if not X) is running on that VT, because you can definitely switch out of allocated-but-unused VTs easily.  If you don't have root and Alt-SysRq nor the normal VT switch shortcuts don't work I think it's hopeless.

Answer (score 0):

What about <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd>?